# How to remove parentheses from array element

Tags: ios, core-data, uitextfield, nsarray, nsfetchrequest

I have an iOS app that uses Core Data to persist information retrieved from a server.  I use a basic fetch request to grab all the `managedObjects` for a given `entity`.  The `managedObjects` are put into an array which I use to populate a `tableViewController`.  Each cell in the table has a `UITextField` that I am trying to put the information into.  I can get the data into the text field but each element comes with parentheses around them.  **How can I get rid of these and just show the text?**

Here is the fetch request:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.managedObjectContext;
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"UserInfo" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];    
NSArray *objects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Here is what I am using to populate the text fields:

```
self.middleNameField.text = [[objects valueForKey:@"firstName"] description];
self.middleNameField.text = [[objects valueForKey:@"middleName"] description];
self.lastNameField.text = [[objects valueForKey:@"lastName"] description];
```

Here is what the response looks like

[image]

This question has been asked a few times but all seem to be looking to display all contents of the array at once rather than a particular element.  Some recommend the method below.

```
self.firstNameField.text = [[[objects valueForKey:@"firstName"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""]description];
```

But I get this exception error.

```
-[__NSArrayI stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Could someone point me in the right direction on this?  I realize I may be going about this all the wrong way.  Don't hesitate to recommend a better method to accomplish the same task.   **Snippets Really Help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns an array because you are asking an array for valueForKey

[objects valueForKey:@"firstName"]

I would suggest this:

```
NSArray *objects = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];  
NSManagedObject *object = [objects lastObject];
if (object) {
  self.middleNameField.text = [object valueForKey:@"firstName"];
  self.middleNameField.text = [[object valueForKey:@"middleName"];
  self.lastNameField.text = [[object valueForKey:@"lastName"];
}
```

You may want to set those fields to @"" if the objects array is empty.  Depends on whether they could have been populated before.

I'm also not a fan of using NSManagedObject *object if you can use the proper subclass generated for your model.  Assuming that the class in question is Person

```
Person *person = [objects lastObject];
if (person) {
  self.middleNameField.text = person.firstName;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply KHansenSF!  Took me a second to get it working because `[objects valueForKey:@"firstName"]` should be `[object ...]` but once I caught that it rolled out perfectly.  Great solution!  If you care to elaborate on the benefits of the subclass you suggest I would love to learn!

Comment: You are absolutely correct.  I fat fingered that one and will edit my answer.  Thanks for pointing that out!  And sorry if that slowed you up!